# Find maximum occurence value across multiple Column (say Two) in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe (df1), and have column `HostCity1` and `HostCity2`, I would like to know which city across these two column has maximum occurence? In this case it is London, but how to identify and assign it to a object (say city_max)

---

```
***import pandas as pd
  olympic_data_list={'HostCity1':['London','Beijing','Athens'],'Year1':[2012,2008,2004],'HostCity2':['London','Sydney','Atlanta'],'Year2':[1948,2000,1996]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(olympic_data_list)
print(df1)***
```

---

The output is:

```
    HostCity1   Year1   HostCity2   Year2
0   London      2012    London      1948
1   Beijing     2008    Sydney      2000
2   Athens      2004    Atlanta     1996
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get columns with `HostCity`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - by default output is sorted, so for top1 value select first index value by indexing `[0]`:

```
city_max = df1.filter(like='HostCity').stack().value_counts().index[0]
print (city_max)
London
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1.filter(like='HostCity'))
  HostCity1 HostCity2
0    London    London
1   Beijing    Sydney
2    Athens   Atlanta

print (df1.filter(like='HostCity').stack())
0  HostCity1     London
   HostCity2     London
1  HostCity1    Beijing
   HostCity2     Sydney
2  HostCity1     Athens
   HostCity2    Atlanta
dtype: object

print (df1.filter(like='HostCity').stack().value_counts())
London     2
Beijing    1
Athens     1
Atlanta    1
Sydney     1
dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot:

```
city_max = df1.filter(like='HostCity').melt()['value'].value_counts().index[0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Pandas, can you explain the logic here..especially the stack function..and why index[0]..Thanks for quick reply,highly appreciated :)

Comment: @ArunMenon - `stack()` is used for unpivot - here from 2 columns data  by `df1.filter(like='HostCity')` is created `Series` for possible count all values together. `Series` contains index and values, after `value_counts()` get sorted counts, so for maximal count only select first value of index by `index[0]`. If still something clear, let me know

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for the explanation!..this answer is quite useful

Comment: @ArunMenon - Added `print` to `details` for see how it working. ;) Happy coding!